# Telegram как спарсить из группы, канала все телефоны и имена, никнеймы и фото участников

Tags: python, парсер, api, telegram

Telegram с помощью Python как спарсить из группы, канала все телефоны и имена, никнеймы и фото, и когда последний раз был участник.

https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser

но не могу понять как начать например на на конкретном чате https://t.me/warsaw_warszawa

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Comment: я так понимаю нужно будет создать бота, которые сможет парсить внутри чужой группы данные (если есть возможность добавить бота)? Если да, а если нет возможности добавление бота то как спарсить данные?

Comment: Тогда возможно подойдёт Telethon, он вроде поддерживает API от имени пользователя